# Android Studio 1.0 install - a host of problems

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I'm currently an Eclipse user, and am trying to migrate to Android Studio 1.0. I've hit a bunch of problems before getting started with development, with a new project that I generated using the wizard:
1. The final entry from the Android Studio install log was:
"Creating Android virtual device
Unable to create a virtual device: Unable to create Android virtual device"
When I created my new project I got these issues:
2. "Gradle project sync failed"
3. "Rendering problems - missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?"
4. "compileSdkVersion android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7"

This is all without a single line of code or config by me. Where to start diagnosing this lot? (I'm running Windows 7 x64)

Comment: Well, the last one is straightforward enough: point Android Studio to a Java 7 or 8 JDK, rather than the Java 6 JDK that you are presently using. Or, change your `compileSdkVersion` to be something lower than 21. In regards to #1, you have not explained what you did in the AVD Manager that triggered the error. #2 and #3 may be side-effects of #4.

Comment: I **uninstalled Android Studio** as soon as I understood it wasn't fit for me (when I discovered **you can't make any AVD below API Level 10**).

Comment: Re #1: I hadn't even opened the AVD Manager - this happened during the Android Studio install process

Comment: So, be prepared to face **a lot of problems more**, once you install the correct JDK. You will miss Eclipse a lot and possibly want to return to it, as I did.

Comment: @DerGolem You have that much need to support [0.5%](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) of installations?

Comment: @MattGibson: **YES**, I do have that need. And it's **not only API Lebvel 8**. In my calculations, even **the 0.1% of the market** is still a **meaningful portion** of my business.

Comment: @DerGolem Erm. That's not what the graph says, is it? The numbers for API levels 10 and above on that page add up to 99.5%. Or am I missing something? The 9.1 figure on that page is API level 10, not API level 9. (Just curious, as I've recently decided not to bother targeting below API 10 for my next app, based on the numbers on that page...)

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. But, as I said, the **0.1%** of the market is still important for me. I estimate a **40K€ for the 0.1%** of the market - which is **200K€, for the 0.5%** of the market. And with 200K€ I can do **many** things... I could even afford a Samsung Galaxy S5 ;)

Comment: Thanks for CommonsWare - JDK 7 cleared up the problems